# Test Class for Batch job

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

I have this Test Class for Batch Job

```
public class ContactBatchProcess_Dialy_Test {
    static testmethod void ContactBatchProcess_Dialy_Test(){

            // Account Record Type
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Schema.SObjectType.Account; 
            Map<String,Schema.RecordTypeInfo> rtMapByName = d.getRecordTypeInfosByName();
          map<Id, Contact> acctChangeContactsMap = new map<Id, Contact>();
            ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate.ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate(acctChangeContactsMap);


            //Insert Account Code 1 (Null Current Proposal Number)
            Account_Code__c acctCode1 = new Account_Code__c();
            acctCode1.Account_Code__c = 'PHZ';
            insert acctCode1;

            //Insert Account Code 1 (Null Current Proposal Number)
            Account_Code__c acctCode2 = new Account_Code__c();
            acctCode2.Account_Code__c = 'NOV';
            insert acctCode2;

            //Insert Account
            Account account = new Account();
            account.RecordTypeId = rtMapByName.get('Customer/Prospect').getRecordTypeId();
            account.Name = 'TEST ACCOUNT';
            account.Type = 'Global HQ';
            account.Business_Type__c = 'Large Pharmaceutical';
            account.BillingStreet = 'Test Street';
            account.BillingCity = 'Test City';
            account.BillingCountry = 'US';
            account.Billingstate = 'Alabama';
            account.Account_Code__c = acctCode1.Id;
            account.Insideview_ID__c = '12345678';
            insert account;

            //Insert Account
            Account account2 = new Account();
            account2.RecordTypeId = rtMapByName.get('Customer/Prospect').getRecordTypeId();
            account2.Name = 'TEST ACCOUNT2';
            account2.Type = 'Global HQ';
            account2.Business_Type__c = 'Large Pharmaceutical';
            account2.BillingStreet = 'Test Street';
            account2.BillingCity = 'Test City';
            account2.BillingCountry = 'US';
            account2.Billingstate = 'Alabama';
            account2.Account_Code__c = acctCode2.Id;
            account2.Insideview_ID__c = '12345678';
            insert account2;

            Contact ct1 = new Contact();
            ct1.FirstName = 'Garry';
            ct1.LastName = 'Page';
            ct1.Email='larry.page@test.com';
            ct1.Title = 'CEO';
            ct1.Phone = '111-111-1111';
            ct1.AccountId= account.id;
            ct1.InsideView_Id__c = '12121212';
            ct1.InsideView_People_Id__c = 'rl8sVlDHGchIB2aTIf62EzFF-s8UnsBp-UXeLQpGFcVNMJWPrMJUEhQ69eRdwxyz';    
            insert ct1;

            ct1.AccountId = account2.id;

            update ct1;

            test.startTest();
                 ContactBatchProcess_Dialy  ivapi = new ContactBatchProcess_Dialy();
                 DateTime dt10mins = system.now().addminutes(1);
                 String Sch = '0 ' + dt10mins.minute() + ' ' + dt10mins.hour() + ' ' + dt10mins.day() + ' ' + dt10mins.month() + ' ? ' + dt10mins.year();                    
                 System.schedule('ContactBatchProcess_Dialy', Sch, ivapi);
            test.stopTest(); 

        }
    }
}
```

I have this class, Did I call the this Apex class in this test class correctly? i'm stuck at 57 %

```
public with sharing class ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate {
    public static void ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate (map<Id, Contact> acctChangeContactsMap){
    Datetime today = system.today();
    List<AccountContactRelation> acccn = new List<AccountContactRelation>();
    List<Accountcontactrelation> acrn = 
                                         [SELECT AccountId, ContactId, Lastmodifieddate
                                          FROM AccountContactRelation 
                                          where contactid in : acctChangeContactsMap.keyset() and lastmodifieddate = today];

        for (Accountcontactrelation arnt : acrn){ 
                //in the event that the AccountID is not equal to AccountID, it will update the enddate to today's date
                if(arnt.accountid != acctChangeContactsMap.get(arnt.contactid).accountId){ 
                     arnt.enddate = system.today();
                     acccn.add(arnt); 
                  }
                //in the event that the AccountID is equal to Accountid, it will update the enddate to null
                else if(arnt.accountid == acctChangeContactsMap.get(arnt.contactid).accountId){ 
                arnt.enddate = NULL;
                acccn.add(arnt); 
            }
        }   
        //Updates the Enddate to Today/NULL
        update acccn;
        } 
    }
```

While having this BatchJob Class

```
global class ContactBatchProcess_Dialy implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
            map<Id, Contact> acctChangeContactsMap = new map<Id, Contact>();
            String[] historyFields = new String[]{'Account'};  
            Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>();    
            for(Contact cnt : [Select Id, name, createdById, LastModifiedById, Account.name, LastModifiedBy.name, 
                              (Select Field, createdById From Histories 
                               Where Field IN :historyFields 
                               AND DAY_ONLY(CreatedDate) = :system.today())                                       
                               From Contact 
                               Where DAY_ONLY(LastModifiedDate) = :system.today()]){
               boolean accountChanged = false;                    
               for(contactHistory cnth : cnt.histories){ 
                    if(cnth.field == 'Account')
                        accountChanged = true;
               }    
               if(accountChanged)
                   acctChangeContactsMap.put(cnt.id, cnt);
            }                       
            //Call process - Email notification to ACC and creator when Account name changes
            if(acctChangeContactsMap.size() > 0)
            ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate.ContactAccountChangeUpdateEndDate(acctChangeContactsMap);
                //contactAccountNameChangeNotification.emailNotification(acctChangeContactsMap);  

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi All, my colleague helped me and he added the following code to ContactBatchProcess_Dialy  and is now covered 100%, thank you for your help everyone         
           boolean accountChanged = false;   
           if(Test.isRunningTest()){
               accountChanged = true;
           }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your test coverage issue is that testmethods can't mock Field History records - e.g. `ContactHistory`. See [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h6RwAAI)

Thus, when you create the Contacts, no field history is actually created to be retrieved.

The solution to this is long-winded, see a [parallel example here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000h6RwAAI) but basically you'll need to inject a dependency into the method being tested so you can return a list of sobjects (not via DML).

Answer (score 0):

This is not batch apex, it is scheduled apex (just to clarify)

In addition to the other answer, if not testing the actual scheduling part, no need to schedule it in the test. Simply run it:

```
ContactBatchProcess_Dialy  ivapi = new ContactBatchProcess_Dialy();
ivapi.execute(null);
```